# ionic - numeric keyboard only

Tags: ionic-framework, mobile, keyboard, ionic3

I am working on an ionic app to track finances but I need the numbers only + point/comma keyboard (not type=„tel“) keyboard like here:

---

[image]

I already searched for ways to open this keyboard but I only found the way using type=„tel“ but that‘s not what I wanted. So what are your solutions?

Comment: Are you sure there is such a keyboard?  Tel is only # one I think.  What is your platform?

Comment: @PhilipBrack I‘m on iOS. I‘m pretty sure because there are many apps that use this keyboard.

Comment: That keyboard looks custom

Comment: i think you need to do like this <ion-input type="number">

Comment: @MustafaLokhanwala already tried it. It behaves like type=„text“ and opens the normal text keyboard.